# IF condition for a merged text field based on several tex fields

Tags: javascript, text, field, conditional-statements

this is my first questions, my apologies for any unclear aspects of it. Here's what I got:

```
// Get field values
var full_name = getField('Full Name').value;
var full_name2 = getField('Full Name 2').value;

// Build account_name string
var account_name = full_name + " " + "and/or" + " " + full_name2;

// Set this field's value equal to account_name
event.value = account_name;
```

It aggregates two name fields into one for an account opening form and adds "and/or". This form is used for both individual accounts (i.e. one person) and joint accounts (i.e. two persons).

**My question: What coding can I add to suppress/not show the "and/or" if the full name 2 field is empty?**

Thanks a million for your help. Joe

Comment: What language is this? Please *edit your question* to include it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var account_name = full_name2 ? full_name + " " + "and/or" + " " + full_name2 : full_name;
```

or just use an `if/else` condition:

```
if (full_name2) {
    event.value = full_name + " and/or " + full_name2;
} else {
    event.value = full_name;
}
```